# Convert an as86 to fasm

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm, as86

I'm trying to convert this bit of assembly for as86 to fasm. I have 3 questions:

1) Why  `seg es` given an `error: illegal instruction.` this is not valid in 16-bit?

2) Is `mov byte [0],0x41`(FASM syntax) exactly equivalent to `mov [0],#0x41`(as86 syntax)? if isn't,can you show me the equivalent to?

3) Why `entry start` give an error in FASM?

Here's the assemblies codes:

**as86**

```
entry start
start:
       mov ax,#0xb800
       mov es,ax
       seg es
       mov [0],#0x41
       seg es
       mov [1],#0x1f
 loop1: jmp loop1
```

and the fasm version that I wrote:

**FASM**

```
use16
format binary

start:
    mov ax,0xb800
    mov es,ax
    seg es
    mov byte [0],0x41
    seg es
    mov byte [1],0x1f
loop1:  jmp loop1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
mov byte [es:0],0x41    ;I'm not sure if this instruction is supported under 16 bit CPU
```

or

```
push bx 
mov  bx,0   ;you can use also: xor  bx, bx
mov  byte [es:bx],0x41
pop  bx
```

Comment: Is this assembly fasm's syntax? doesn't works too: `error: reserved word used as symbol.`

Comment: GJ: Yes, `mov byte [es:0],0x41` is a valid 16-bit x86 instruction, NASM encodes it as `26 C6 06 00 00 41`.

Comment: I know that it's valid 16-bit x86 instruction. I'm asking for if is FASM sytax.

Comment: @Jack I meant my comment as a response to GJ to "I'm not sure if this instruction is supported under 16 bit CPU"...

Comment: @nrz: My apologies. I had not seen the 'GJ:' part in the start of string.

Comment: @GJ.: But isn't working for me. I think that isn't valid under 16-bit CPU?

Comment: @Jack: you can try with second example.

Comment: @GJ.: I had tried the second only. `byte [es:ax]` fails but `byte [es:0]` is fine. Thanks.

Comment: @GJ.: So by using `mov byte [es:0],0x41` don't need a `seg es`?

Comment: @Jack: No. The es prefix must be after bracket...  [es:0]

Comment: `ax` cannot be used as a memory address of an instruction operand. Only `bx`, `bp`, `si`, `di` can.

Comment: @GJ.: worked. Is `mov byte [es:1],0x1f` equvalent to `*(es + 1) = 0x1f;` in C?

Comment: @Jack: Check with disassembler!

Answer (score 0):

`seg es` looks fishy. Try following:

```
mov byte ptr es:[0],0x41
```

Comment: doesn't works for me: `s.asm [21]:
        mov byte ptr es:[0],0x41
error: invalid expression.`